Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
I tried to connect my Epson M1100 printer to the RaspberryPi through USB and then create a printing server in my network.

I installed drivers with wget https://download3.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/03/00/15/68/87/02d1b47f60d5010bbd44ace4eccee78ac4017b61/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.8.5_armhf.deb && sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.8.5_armhf.deb
then cups with sudo apt install cups -y and enabled and turned services on
next, I've added user to the lpadmin with lpadmin sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin $USER, then I've setup remote access to cups with cupsctl --remote-admin --remote-any --share-printers.

I then added the printer with the sharing option and proper drivers through the browser UI (my Macbook could easily connect to the RPI at https://192.168.0.103:631/printers/) from the internal network.
But when I added the printer EPSON M1100 Series @ raspberrypi in MacOS, and made a test print of any document, I get the status "Printing on server, <my name>, Rendering Complete" in the "Printer queue..." (and it's stuck there). When I open the error log /var/log/cups/error_log, I get [Job 1] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe twice for this print job.
When I canceled the job and tried to print simple text through echo "Nice" | lp -d EPSON_M1100_Series on the RPI itself, I got response request id is EPSON_M1100_Series-5 (0 file(s)), but again the printer doesn't print and in the logs, I get HUGE logs
E [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] The following messages were recorded from 10:02:38 to 10:02:38
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Applying default options...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Adding start banner page "none".
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Queued on "EPSON_M1100_Series" by "ether".
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Auto-typing file...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Request file type is text/plain.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] File of type text/plain queued by "ether".
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Adding end banner page "none".
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] time-at-processing=1723363358
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] 4 filters for job:
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] texttopdf (text/plain to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/EPSON_M1100_Series, cost 0)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] job-sheets=none,none
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[0]="EPSON_M1100_Series"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[1]="5"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[2]="ether"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[3]="(stdin)"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[4]="1"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[5]="finishings=3 number-up=1 print-color-mode=color job-uuid=urn:uuid:46eeb3eb-aef6-3875-767a-01ad94bd61b5 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1723363358 time-at-processing=1723363358"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00005-001"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[3]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[4]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[6]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[7]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[8]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[9]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[10]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.4.2"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[11]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[12]="USER=root"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[13]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[18]="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/EPSON_M1100_Series.ppd"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[20]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[21]="DEVICE_URI=usb://EPSON/M1100%20Series?serial=5835484B3030353876"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[22]="PRINTER_INFO=EPSON M1100 Series"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[23]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[24]="PRINTER=EPSON_M1100_Series"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[25]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[26]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[27]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[28]="AUTH_I****"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf (PID 22427)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 22428)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 22429)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Started filter /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper (PID 22430)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 22431)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PID 22430 (/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper) stopped with status 102 (No such file or directory)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] execv failed: No such file or directory
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Loaded 118 quirks.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Printing on printer with URI: usb://EPSON/M1100%20Series?serial=5835484B3030353876
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: epson-escpr-wrapper; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] OUTFORMAT=\"<none>\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Page = 595x842; 8,8 to 587,833
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] libusb_get_device_list=5
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] iSerialNumber=\"5835484B3030353876\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Printer found with device ID: MFG:EPSON;CMD:ESCPL2,BDC,D4,D4PX,ESCPR1,END4;MDL:M1100 Series;CLS:PRINTER;DES:EPSON M1100 Series;CID:EpsonRGB;FID:FXN,DPN,WFN,ETN,AFN,DAN,WRN;RID:41;DDS:022180;ELG:1260; Device URI: usb://EPSON/M1100%20Series?serial=5835484B3030353876
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Device protocol: 2
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Read 182 bytes of back-channel data...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PID 22427 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) exited with no errors.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Sending data to printer.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Sent 0 bytes...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] pdftopdf: \"print-scaling\" IPP attribute: auto
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] pdftopdf: Print scaling mode: Do not scale, center, crop if needed
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] After Cropping: 595.000000 842.000000 595.200012 841.799988
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PID 22428 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-EPSON_M1100_Series)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_EPSON_M1100_Series
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-EPSON_M1100_Series)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_EPSON_M1100_Series
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(RGB.PLAIN_NORMAL....)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Found profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/EPSON_M1100_Series_RGB__
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Profile.Get(Filename)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Failed to get profile filename for cups-EPSON_M1100_Series
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Color Manager: ICC Profile:
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r360x360 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=841 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -dcupsCompression=1 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[8.400000 8.400000 8.400024 8.399963] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[3]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[4]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[6]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[7]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[8]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[9]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[10]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.4.2\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[11]=\"TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[18]=\"LANG=en_GB.UTF-8\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/EPSON_M1100_Series.ppd\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[20]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[21]=\"DEVICE_URI=usb://EPSON/M1100%20Series?serial=5835484B3030353876\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[22]=\"PRINTER_INFO=EPSON M1100 Series\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[24]=\"PRINTER=EPSON_M1100_Series\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[25]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[26]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[27]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] envp[28]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Start rendering...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Processing page 1...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] **** Error: Page drawing error occurred.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Could not draw this page at all, page will be missing in the output.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Rendering completed
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PID 22429 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] PID 22431 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] End of messages
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] printer-state=3(idle)
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [11/Aug/2024:10:02:38 +0200] [Job 2] printer-state-reasons=none

What I miss here?

I've found the issue and figured out how to fix it. There were two main problems: a missing 32-bit ARM interpreter (the drivers were only compatible with it, but the Raspberry Pi has a 64-bit OS) and some missing libraries. So, I decided to compile the drivers myself.
First, I uninstalled the drivers I had previously installed. Then, I downloaded the source code from here (on the bottom you have Or if you want to use the source package for arm CPU, please click here.) and navigated to the directory where the Epson Inkjet Printer Driver (ESC/P-R) source code was located. To compile the driver, I ran the following commands:
./configure
make
sudo make install

During the compilation process, I ran into an error related to a missing cups/cups.h header file. I fixed this by installing the CUPS development package using the command sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev.
After installing the missing package, I ran the compilation and installation commands again. This time, the installation completed successfully, and the epson-escpr and epson-escpr-wrapper files were installed in the /usr/local/lib/cups/filter directory. To double-check, I used the command ls /usr/local/lib/cups/filter | grep epson.
Then, I copied all ppd files, so proper model will be available in CUPS web interface with command sudo cp ppd/*.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/
Next, I restarted the CUPS service and checked the CUPS configuration files for any references to the epson-escpr driver using sudo grep -r "epson-escpr" /etc/cups/. No references were found, which meant that CUPS wasn't configured to use the driver yet.
I then accessed the CUPS web interface through a web browser and tried to add the Epson printer using the installed driver. However, I encountered an error message saying that the file /usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper wasn't available.
To resolve this, I created a symbolic link from /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper to /usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper using the command sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper /usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper.
After creating the symbolic link, I restarted the CUPS service once more. Finally, I was able to successfully add the printer through the CUPS web interface and print a test page.
